# Помогите составить запрос.

Tags: запрос, mysql

Есть таблица:

```
id  |   state   |   datetime    
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   0       |   2013-10-12 12:45:00
2   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:00:00
3   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:15:00
4   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:30:00
5   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:45:00
6   |   0       |   2013-10-12 14:00:00
7   |   1       |   2013-10-12 14:15:00
8   |   1       |   2013-10-12 14:30:00
9   |   1       |   2013-10-12 14:45:00
```

Нужно получить результат выборки:

```
id  |   state   |   datetime    
---------------------------------------------------
1   |   0       |   2013-10-12 12:45:00
2   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:00:00
5   |   1       |   2013-10-12 13:45:00
6   |   0       |   2013-10-12 14:00:00
7   |   1       |   2013-10-12 14:15:00
9   |   1       |   2013-10-12 14:45:00
```

т.е. Если state одинаковый у близлежащих записей, то в выборку попадала только первая и последняя запись.

Спасибо.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что что-то не так с организацией БД. Но так как такие ответы сам ненавижу и не считаю профессиональными, понаблюдаю как же можно ЭТО запросить.

Лично у меня напрашивается только сложный многоуровневый запрос с разбиением по группам при помощи внутренней группировки, выборка min/max и еще одна группировка для исключения дублей.

Comment: @knes ага. "Предчувствия его не обманули" ((c) "Пиф-паф")

    select a.* from t a join
      (select min(id) as i1, max(id) as i2 from
        (select id, state, case @s when state then @g else @g := @g + 1 end g, @s := state
            from t b join (select @s := 0, @g := 0) c) d group by g) e
    on a.id in (e.i1, e.i2);